# Menu Activity doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, button, menuitem

I have  several buttons and list view at my app home screen. And I want to put menu activity at it. So I just wrote my custom menu activity and extends from home screen. But unfortunately that my custom menu doesn't working when I clicked menu button at my phone. Any ideas ?

```
package com.gokiri.gl.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.gokiri.gl.R;
import com.gokiri.gl.screen.GLandMainMenu;
import com.gokiri.gl.screen.SearchScreen;
import com.gokiri.gl.util.Shared;

public class GLandMainActivity extends ListActivity {
    protected Activity act;
    protected int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    protected Bitmap bannerBitmap;

    protected void initActivity(Activity act) {
        this.act = act;

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = dm.heightPixels;
        dm = null;

        Shared.addAcitivity(act);
        setDefaultButton();
    }

    public void setDefaultButton() {

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
            Shared.removeAcitivity();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GLandMainMenu.class));
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private Menu mMenu;

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.mMenu = menu;
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_home:
            // act.finish();
            Intent main = new Intent(act, GLandMainMenu.class);
            startActivity(main);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_search:
            act.finish();
            Intent search = new Intent(act, SearchScreen.class);
            startActivity(search);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_bookmarks:
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_about:
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
}
```

EDIT from comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_home" 
    android:title="@string/home" 
    android:icon="@drawable/tab_home" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="@string/search" 
    android:icon="@drawable/tab_search" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmarks"
    android:title="@string/bookmark"
    android:icon="@drawable/tab_about" />
  <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:icon="@drawable/tab_about" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Hi geekmyo  may be u not add Activity in Android Manifiest

Comment: Hey parag, i had other menu activities which are used by other screen and never add in mainfiest file. It's working as well without declare at mainfiest. Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the problem that the menu is not shown when you press the menu button on the phone? Or is it that the menu is shown, but it does not react when you press a menu item?

Comment: Hi Emil H, my problem is that menu is not shown when i pressed menu button on both emulator and phone. thanks

Comment: Hi, What does the menu xml resource look like? Maybe you are using the wrong id?

Comment: **Update** here's my xml layout. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_home" android:title="@string/home"
  android:icon="@drawable/tab_home" /> 
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_search" android:title="@string/search"
  android:icon="@drawable/tab_search" />
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmarks" android:title="@string/bookmark"
  android:icon="@drawable/tab_about" />
 <item android:id="@+id/menu_about" android:title="@string/about"
  android:icon="@drawable/tab_about" />
</menu>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what i see , you blocking the onCreateOptionMenu() with the onKeyDown who intercept the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU. You can't use the menu button for both launching activity and displaying menu (obviously). And if this is not that , explain us what's the GLandMainMenu class

Comment: hi eephyne, your answer rocks. **problem solved** all i have to do is that remove onKeyDown function from the code. Thanks